# How to select from 2 different tables and order them by one column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a MySQLi query that selects from two tables in the database that differ in structure but the have a common column I want to make it ordered by.

E.g.:

```
table one:
id / post / date
1  / hi man / 13 - 11 - 2013

table two:
id / shared post / date
1  / hey / 12 - 11 - 2013
```

I want to make the query look like this:

```
hey / 12 - 11 - 2013
hi man / 13 - 11 - 2013
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What are the table schemas?

Comment: @jeff id - post content - date 

id - shared post content - date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

Thus:

```
SELECT post, date FROM tableone
UNION SELECT sharedpost, date FROM tabletwo
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want .... thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM x, y WHERE x.post = y.shared_post ORDER BY x.post;
```

You should alter the query to match your table structure.

Comment: thanks for the replay , but the two tables are not the same in any column i only want to echo out them ordered by date so the earlier post comes first ....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id=y.id ORDER BY x.date ASC;
```

You want this?

EDIT :
Maybe you what this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM x UNION SELECT * FROM y) ORDER BY 1 ASC ;
```